# Passing 2D c++ vector to a python function and getting output back as 2D array

Tags: python, c++, c-api

I have been stuck on this for a week now.I am intializing a 2D vector of doubles and passing it to a simple
python function which multiplies it by 2 and returns it.

```
def in_arr_out_arr(arr_input):

    print(arr_input)
    arr_input2 = 2*arr_input

    return (arr_input2)
```

The print function prints garbage values to the console .

Here is the function Called

```
PyObject* call_python_function_vector2d_input(PyObject* function_name, vector<vector<double>> args)
{


    import_array()
    PyObject* np_arg = (PyObject*)vector_to_nparray(args);
    
    PyObject* pReturn, * pArgs;

    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, np_arg);

    pReturn = PyObject_CallObject(function_name, pArgs);
    PyErr_PrintEx(0);
    //cout << pReturn << "\n";

    return pReturn;

}
```

```
static PyArrayObject* vector_to_nparray(vector< vector<double> >& vec, int type_num = PyArray_DOUBLE) {

size_t nRows = vec.size();
size_t nCols = vec[0].size();
npy_intp dims[2] = { nRows, nCols };
PyArrayObject* vec_array = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_SimpleNew(2, dims, type_num);

double* vec_array_pointer = (double*)PyArray_DATA(vec_array);

for (size_t iRow = 0; iRow < vec.size(); ++iRow) 
{
    copy(vec[iRow].begin(), vec[iRow].end(), vec_array_pointer + iRow * nCols);
}

return vec_array;


}
```

This is the last version i tried by reading from some previous answer on this forum only.
It may have something to do with contigous block of memory allocation for np_arg but i dont have that
much expertise in pointers

**UPDATE**

I removed all the functions and simply ran the whole thing in main function.It worked.
Can someone tell  why is not running in function forms. Also , how to run it using seperate functions.

Comment: A two-dimensional array can be represented by a one-dimensional array.  Do you have a one-dimensional array version of your code that works?  Also, `double** args` is **not** a two-dimensional array.  Let's see where `args` comes from, and how it was put together.

Comment: edited the question for passing 2d vector  its still printing garbage values

Comment: Its working for 1d arrays

Comment: You shouldn't have edited the code.  You could have stayed with `double **args`.  I wanted to see how you created the array using `double **args`.  If you created the 2D array [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048), then you could have passed `&args[0][0]` to python, just like a 1d array, along with the number of rows and columns.  Then python would have seen it as a single dimension, but actually you are sending the entire 2d array.  Then you fix the python code (I am no python expert) to simulate the 2d array.

Comment: What you newly edited code does is worse, in that you are now creating many vectors and not in contiguous memory, causing a very cache-unfriendly scenario.